# Несет ли ответственность за свои программы программист?

Tags: юридические-аспекты

Если заказывают у программиста какой-то сайт, который может использоваться как в хорошем, так и плохом деле. Будут ли проблемы у самого программиста? Или это касается только того, кто руководит? В данный момент поступил заказ (смс обработчик). и меня неофициально делают главным по тех. поддержки. Если я буду делать то, что говорят, на меня ответственность ложится?

Comment: Если есть договор, то в нем все это должно указываться. Что называется ответственности сторон. А если нет, то я бы проконсультировался с юристом.

Comment: @zhenyab, договор словесный, но кто как знает.

Comment: согласен, словестный договор - это не договор.

Comment: @Node_pro, думаю, если текст обрабатываемых смс-ок Вы не будете менять (в смысле *ненависть, мятеж, наркотики...коды для взлома* и т.д.), то в случае словесного договора официально Вам вообще ничего предъявить не получится (например, если пропало сообщение).

Уволить не заплатив, могут, реально это просто. 

--

С другой стороны, Вы же понимаете, что у нас "был бы человек, а статья найдется".

Comment: avp, предоплата будет. А так, пугает законность. Вроде и правда не чего нет в этом, но спросил на всякий случай. Спасибо за ответ!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Думаю, смотря что вы будете делать. [УК РФ. ст 273](http://www.zakonrf.info/uk/273/) - если вы сами будете создавать или использовать. но по 272 или 274 могут и без этого. Вообще вот [Глава 28. Преступления в сфере компьютерной информации](http://www.zakonrf.info/uk/gl28/) .

Если техподдержка не будет скрывать что-то нелегальное и не будет обманывать, то думаю только по этим смогут привлекать, иначе по многим могут.

Хотя сейчас законы в этой области переписываются, торренты там всякие закрывают=).

Comment: А можно с Вами пообщаться в привате?

Comment: я учил это в институте, так как учился на программиста. Но если хотите, то icq 1456757. Могу жабу дать, если там удобнее.

Comment: @spirit, ой а у Вас нет скайпа или иных средств?

Comment: дожили, аська с жабой не в ходу=) скайпом я не пользуюсь уже давно. Может смогу здесь ответить?